# Set text color in QListWidget after checking more than an amount of options

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlistwidget

I have created a QListWidget that are populated with checkboxes and I had wanted to code it in such a way that, if more than 3 items within the list are checked, the 'fourth' item that is to be checked, the text color will be colored red.

Currently, I am having the issue where all the text will be colored red as soon as the fourth item has been checked, where I am only expecting the fourth (and beyond) checked item will be colored red, not all.

This is my code:

```
class PromptDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, items_list, parent=None):
        super(PromptDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("My Test Dialog")
        self.init_ui(items_list)
        self.init_connections()

    def init_ui(self, items_list):
        self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget()
        for item in items_list:
            list_widget_item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(item)
            # could be Qt.Unchecked; setting it makes the check appear
            list_widget_item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.listWidget.addItem(list_widget_item)

        get_sels_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Save Selections")

        cancel_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")
        cancel_btn.clicked.connect(self.close)

        hbox_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox_layout.addWidget(self.listWidget, 1)

        btns_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        btns_layout.addStretch(1)
        btns_layout.addWidget(get_sels_btn)
        btns_layout.addWidget(cancel_btn)

        vbox_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox_layout.addLayout(hbox_layout)
        vbox_layout.addSpacing(12)
        vbox_layout.addLayout(btns_layout)

        self.setLayout(vbox_layout)

    def init_connections(self):
        self.listWidget.clicked.connect(self.derived_checked_opts)

    def derived_checked_opts(self):
        checked_items = []
        for index in range(self.listWidget.count()):
            if self.listWidget.item(index).checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                checked_items.append(self.listWidget.item(index))

            if len(checked_items) > 3:
                self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("color: red")
            else:
                self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("color: none")


some_items = ['item01', 'item02', 'item03', 'item04', 'item05', 'item06']
my_dialog = PromptDialog(some_items)
my_dialog.show()
```

Example case of what I am expecting:

1. If any of the 3 options (3 or less) are checked, the text remains white

---

```
[x] item01
[x] item02
[x] item03
[] item04
[] item05
[] item06
```

2. Now I am going to check one or more options (fourth item and more)

---

```
[x] item01 --> Text remains white
[x] item02 --> Text remains white
[x] item03 --> Text remains white
[x] item04 --> Text will turns red
[] item05
[] item06
```

Currently what I am having trouble with is the Case #2, is all text turns red:

```
[x] item01 --> Text turns red
[x] item02 --> Text turns red
[x] item03 --> Text turns red
[x] item04 --> Text turns red
[] item05 --> Text turns red
[] item06 --> Text turns red
```

Comment: you could explain me better, you could give an example of the cases, I really do not understand you

Comment: @eyllanesc Say I have checked `item01`, item02` and `item03`. If I am going to check `item04`, all the items' text within the QListWidget turns red. I had only wanted `item04` (fourth item onwards) text to turn red only. Meaning to say `item01-03` still remains white

Comment: okay, I understand, and if you press a fifth item should that item be painted too?

Comment: Yes, fifth item's text will be red too, only the first 3 selection's text will be white

Comment: Okay, I'm going to give you a new case, let's say that items item1, item2, item3, item4 are checked in that order so depending on what you point out item4 should be red, and then I do unchecked in item1 so there will only be 3 items with checked Does item4 have to stay red?

Comment: In that case, item4 will be white as there are 3 checked items.

Comment: Okay, I understood you